# A specific local martingale

Tags: proof-verification, martingales, stopping-times, local-martingales

Knowing that M and N are two local martingales.
Can I do the following simple reasoning for claiming that $N^\tau(M^\tau - M)$ is a local martingale?

: Since a stopped local martingale is still a local martingale, and since the product of two local martingale is still a local martingale, then $N^\tau M^\tau$.
Applying the same reasoning also at $N^\tau M$ I could conclude that it is also a local martingale.
Finally the difference of 2 local martingale is still a local martingale.

It follows that $N^\tau(M^\tau - M)$ is a local martingale.

If this reasoning does not hold, what is wrong? How could I prove it without using Ito or advanced techniques?

Comment: Are $M$ and $N$ independent?

Comment: @d.k.o. I don't read it anyway, I deduce that they are not.

Comment: The product of two local martingales is not always a local martingale. I remember reading a question here on MSE asking about it. There should be a comment with a link to a paper that discusses in issue in detail.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist ok, thank you for spotting the error. Do you have any suggestion for the resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M^{(n)}$ and $N^{(n)}$ denote $M$ and $N$ stopped at $\sigma_n\wedge\tau_n$. These are both bounded martingales. Form $X^{(n)}_t:=N^{(n)}_{t\wedge\tau}(M^{(n)}_{t\wedge\tau}-M^{(n)}_t)$. As previously noted (now corrected), 
$$
X^{(n)}_t=\cases{0,&$0\le t<\tau$,\cr  N^{(n)}_\tau(M^{(n)}_{\tau}-M^{(n)}_t),&$t\ge \tau$.\cr}
$$
Now decompose (for $0\le s<t$)
$$
X^{(n)}_t=(1_{\{s<t\le\tau\}}+1_{\{s<\tau\le t\}} +1_{\{\tau\le s<t\}})\cdot X^{(n)}_t
$$
into three terms. The conditional expectation of the first term (given $\mathcal F_s$) is trivial; for the second use the tower property of conditional expectations, conditioning first on $\mathcal F_\tau$; the third is easy because $M^{(n)}$ is a martingale and $N^{(n)}_\tau\cdot 1_{\{\tau\le s<t\}}$ is $\mathcal F_s$-measurable.
It follows that $X^{(n)}$ is a martingale (for each $n$), and then that $X$ is a local martingale.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that your product of local martingales, call it $X$, is equal to
$$
X_t=\cases{0,&$0\le t<\tau$,\cr  N_\tau(M_{\tau}-M_t),&$t\ge \tau$,\cr}
$$
If, for example, $M$ and $N$ are continuous local martingales (or, more generally, locally bounded local martingales) then by localizing you can reduce to the case in which both $M$ and $N$ are bounded martingales. In this case it is clear that $X$ is integrable, and it is straightforward to compute $\Bbb E[X_t|\mathcal F_s]$ for $0\le s<t$, to see that $X$ is a martingale.

Comment: I'm not so sure to having understand your approach, so I will say how I have interpreted it. (note: I will use $\tau_n$ and $\sigma_n$ as the original localising stopping time seq. of M and N). When t<$\tau$ I have = 0 because it become ($M_{t \land \tau_n} - M_{t \land \tau_n})$ inside the parenthesis. When t$\ge \tau$ instead $X_t = N_{\tau \land \sigma_n}(M_{\tau \land \tau_n} - M_{t \land \tau_n})$. Now, E[$X_t|\mathbb F_s]= X_s = N_{\tau \land \sigma_n}(M_{\tau \land \tau_n} - M_{s \land \tau_n})$ since $N_{\tau \land \sigma_n}$ and $M_{\tau \land \tau_n}$ are stopped bounded martingale.

Comment: Notice tha if $\tau_n$ localizes $M$ and $\sigma_n$ localizes $N$, then $\tau_n\wedge\sigma_n$ localizes both $M$ and $N$.

Comment: Also, to compute the conditional expectation of $X$ stopped at $\tau_n\wedge\sigma_n$, break into three cases according as $t<\tau$, $s<\tau\le\tau$, or $\tau\le s$.